# read_csv: delimiter before end-of-line(EOL) leads to wrong column number

Tags: python, pandas

When the values in a file end with a separator, the columns read in with read_csv are not assigned properly. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

# File content
columns = ['A','B']
data = [[1,2], [3,4]]

# Generate very simple test file
with open('test.dat', 'w') as fh:
    fh.writelines('{0}\t{1}'.format(*columns))
    for line in data:
        fh.write('\n')
        for val in line:
            # This is the crux: there is a tab-delimiter after each value,
            # even the last one!
            fh.write('{0}\t'.format(val))

# Try to read it
df = pd.read_csv('test.dat', sep='\t', index_col=None)
print(df)
```

produces

```
   A   B
1  2 NaN
3  4 NaN
```

Is this a bug, or a feature?

In this specific case, the problem can be fixed with

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.dat', sep='\t', index_col=None, usecols=['A','B'])
```

correctly produces

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

However, for files with an unknown, large number of columns, this fix is inconvenient. Is there any option to "pd.read_csv" that can fix this problem?

Comment: The definition of a separator is "something which separates other things" so having one at the end of your lines is strange.

Comment: it seems to me that this is the desired behavior--how would you specify a column of NANs at the end if not with an extra delimiter? I would suggest removing the trailing tab before use. You can use sed to do this if the file is very large.

Comment: actually, looking closer at what you have, I do think this is a bug--it should have an 'Unamed - 2' column at the end, with all NANs. You should report it!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, adding the * quantifier to the sep argument seems to work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.dat', sep='\t*', index_col=None)
```

Comment: That seems like a bug to me.